# Is pin polarity a requirement in this TVS diode array?

Tags: esd, tvs

I have a 4-channel [TI TPD4EUSB30](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpd4eusb30.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1653607799647&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Ftpd4eusb30) TVS/ESD diode array that I've been using successfully on differential ethernet traces. Our design changed and the positive and negative pins have swapped positions which means I would have to flip the traces if I am to observe the indicated polarity on the TVS. However, I am not convinced that polarity needs to be observed because all channels are simply connected between two diodes as shown on the device schematic:

[image: TI TPD4EUSB30]

A similar [Nexperia PUSB3F96](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PUSB3F96.pdf) doesn't label the channels with any sort of polarity indication:

[image: Nexperia PUSB3F96]

**Is there any reason I can't simply ignore the polarity on the TI device and avoid having to swap the positions of my differential traces?** Nowhere in the datasheet are specifications given that differ between the D+ and D- pins. Is there any particular reason TI have labeled the channels with + and -?

Comment: The only problem I could possibly see is something about one pin being connected to the die substrate or something, but that feels unlikely to be a problem for this, it's just the only potential problem I can imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just to suggest a typical layout.  I don't see any differences between channels.

A similar protip: transformers don't care about P/N, RX/TX etc. They're identical and symmetrical, *as long as you make the same changes on both sides* (i.e. swap primary and secondary polarity).  (Although that isn't even much of an issue, with almost all PHYs supporting Auto MDIX.)  So layouts can often be simplified this way.